# Prerelease build not opening in iphone

Tags: objective-c, xcode6, app-store-connect, testflight, beta-testing

I have uploaded successfuly my build using Xcode 6 to iTunes connect and my testers too get the mail to upload via test flight when i click the link it goes to test flight but nothing appears over there.Even i don't get any error.

I have tried with both development and Ad-hoc provisioning profile where am doing wrong...please suggest.

Comment: I have the same problem! I am currently waiting for a response from the itunes connect people. They are looking into it. I also have an error where if the app does show up on testflight it has "expired" next to it.

Answer (score 1):

You MUST use Apple Mail to open the link from within your email on your phone. Using Gmail doesn't work (... I believe it did previously with Burstly TestFlight).

Apparently it doesn't matter if you use a different Apple ID to the invited email address, although it probably should be set on the phone as your primary Apple ID. See this article:

https://medium.com/ios-os-x-development/internal-testflight-testers-with-multiple-itunes-connect-accounts-3c5adbab16e1